# CSS background pattern for grip boxes

Tags: html, css, background-image

I would like to use CSS to create a "grip" background used to indicate that an element is draggable. (See https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/34639/39138)

Currently I have a `dnd` class for the item, and CSS that looks like:

```
.dnd {
  background: #99bbee; /* would like to be able to change this dynamically */
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  width: 14em;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.dnd:hover {
  box-shadow: 0.25em 0.25em 0.3em rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 1.75em 2.1em 2.25em 1.9em;
  cursor: move; /* fallback if grab cursor is unsupported */
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.dnd:active { 
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
.dnd::before { /* the grip */
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: -0.5em 0.75em -0.5em -0.5em; 

  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background-position: 0 0;
  /* Background image - unfortunately requires background color */
  background-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(#99bbee 50%, transparent 50%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(#99bbee 50%, transparent 50%),
    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: 
    -o-linear-gradient(#99bbee 50%, transparent 50%),
    -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(#99bbee 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

...This works in creating a few boxes as a background on the grip, but I would like to not have the grip pseudo-element rely on a hard-coded background color (in this case `#99bbee`; it's OK that it uses `rgba(0,0,0,0.2)`). Is there a way to rewrite this CSS background image so that it is more flexible w/r/t background color?

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/luken/r69wfwjd/5/

---

**2021 Edit:** [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) are now widely supported, so they are probably the best solution.

Comment: CSS variables? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 5):

I think  the best option might be an SVG image background.

In fact, if you take a look at stackoverflow's own grip to expand the textarea (`.grippie`) when writing an answer, it uses an [SVG background](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=d689de80c4e2).

So the idea is to use the css `background` property with `url(...)` and a [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) as the url.

The SVG code was taken from [here](https://philiprogers.com/svgpatterns/#subtledots).

```css
.grip {
  background-size: cover;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUiPgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSIjODg4Ij48L3JlY3Q+Cjwvc3ZnPg==");
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" draggable="true">
  <div class="grip"></div>
  <div class="content">A thing with a grip</div>
</div>
<div class="container" draggable="true">
  <div class="grip"></div>
  <div class="content">A thing with a grip</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get this effect using multiple shadows for the pseudo element:

```css
.dnd {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  width: 14em;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  font-family: Arial;
}


.dnd::before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  margin: 0em 1.5em 0em -1em; 

  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0.5em -1em 0 gray,
              0.5em -0.25em 0 gray,
              0.5em 0.5em 0 gray,
              0.5em 1.25em 0 gray,
              1.25em -1em 0 gray,
              1.25em -0.25em 0 gray,
              1.25em 0.5em 0 gray,
              1.25em 1.25em 0 gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="dnd">
Thing that can be dragged
</div>
```

I have created a snippet where the grid is always a darker version of the background.

There are 2 diagonal gradients, that joint to create a square

```css
.dnd {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  width: 14em;
  transition: all 0.25s;
  font-family: Arial;
}


.dnd::before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: -0.5em 0.75em -0.5em -0.5em; 

  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 0.5em 0.5em;
  background-position: 0 0, 0.25em 0.25em;

  background-image: 
linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0.1768em, transparent 0.1767em),
linear-gradient(225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0.1768em, transparent 0.1767em);
  

}
```

```html
<div class="dnd">
Thing that can be dragged
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good but there is a slight 1px overlap in the triangles. Can you explain how you derived the angles and the size measurements?

Comment: The angles are to target the diagonal in ascending or descending direction. The size of the squares is 0.25em, so half the diagonal is square root of 2 * 0.25 / 2

Comment: I have added a better solution

Answer (score 1):

If you take a simple set of dots like `....`, then rotate them 90 degrees, then turn on text-shadow to repeat them, then you can achieve this with very little CSS.

```css
i.grip::after
{
content: "....";
display: inline-block;
color: #AAA;
font-style: normal;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size:15px;
font-weight: bold;
transform: rotate(90deg);
text-shadow: 0px -4px 0px #AAA;
cursor:move;
margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div><i class="grip"></i> Drag Me By My Handle</div>
```